# Generate an entire object Graph Interface

Tags: c#

I have a large nested xsd generated object model which I would like to create interfaces for so as to create proxy objects.  Is there a tool that will generate all of the interfaces I need or will I just need to generate them manually one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`xsd.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) to generate C# classes for you - you can then use the [extract interface refactoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3dyx26.aspx) to generate interfaces from these.

Comment: I am aware of that tool.  The xsd is huge and generated ~100 classes in a deep structure.  I wanted a tool that could walk the tree until you reached primitive types.

Comment: @rerun  if that is what you need, why didn't you ask that in you question?

Comment: @Oded That's what he asked: "entire object Graph"